# Display data using ajax and laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have the following model in my blade view :

```
<div class="modal fade modal-right select-from-library" id="libraryModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
            aria-labelledby="libraryModal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Select from Library</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
               
                    <div class="modal-body scroll pt-0 pb-0 mt-4 mb-4">
                        <div class="accordion" id="accordion">
                            <div class="mb-2">
                                <button class="btn btn-link p-0 folder-button-collapse" data-toggle="collapse"
                                    data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                    <span class="icon-container">
                                        <i class="simple-icon-arrow-down"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="folder-name">Castings</span>
                                </button>
                                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
                                    <div class="list disable-text-selection">
                                        <div class="row">
                                         <div class = "ok">
                                            <div class="col-6 mb-1 sfl-item-container casting"
                                                data-preview-path="img/products/chocolate-cake-thumb.jpg"
                                                data-path="img/products/chocolate-cake-thumb.jpg"
                                                data-label="chocolate-cake-thumb.jpg">
                                                <div class="card d-flex mb-2 p-0 media-thumb-container casting2">
                                                    <div class="d-flex align-self-stretch">
                                                        <img src="img/products/chocolate-cake-thumb.jpg" alt="uploaded image"
                                                            class="list-media-thumbnail responsive border-0" />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 min-width-zero">
                                                        <div
                                                            class="card-body pr-1 pt-2 pb-2 align-self-center d-flex min-width-zero">
                                                            <div class="w-100 name_casting">
                                                                <p class="truncate mb-0">OK</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div
                                                            class="custom-control custom-checkbox pl-1 pr-1 align-self-center">
                                                            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-0">
                                                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
                                                                <span class="custom-control-label"></span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                         

                                         </div>   
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary sfl-submit">Selectionner</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And I get data from databse and I shouls display data in this model
So I'm using the following scipt :

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#numero_projet').change(function(){

            var id_projet = $(this).find("option:selected").data("id");

            console.log(id_projet);

        $.ajaxSetup({

            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 
        $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }

          });
        
        $.ajax({
                  
            url:"getProjet/"+id_projet,
            type:"GET",

            success:function(html){
            renderTemplate(html)
    }        

        });

         function renderTemplate(html) {
        var 
content = html.castings.map((casting) => ` <div class="row"> <div class="col-6 mb-1 sfl-item-container casting"
                                                data-preview-path="img/products/chocolate-cake-thumb.jpg"
                                                data-path="img/products/chocolate-cake-thumb.jpg"
                                                data-label="chocolate-cake-thumb.jpg">
                                                <div class="card d-flex mb-2 p-0 media-thumb-container casting2">
                                                    <div class="d-flex align-self-stretch">
                                                        <img src="img/products/chocolate-cake-thumb.jpg" alt="uploaded image"
                                                            class="list-media-thumbnail responsive border-0" />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 min-width-zero">
                                                        <div
                                                            class="card-body pr-1 pt-2 pb-2 align-self-center d-flex min-width-zero">
                                                            <div class="w-100 name_casting">
                                                                <p class="truncate mb-0">${casting.id_casting}</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div
                                                            class="custom-control custom-checkbox pl-1 pr-1 align-self-center">
                                                            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-0">
                                                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
                                                                <span class="custom-control-label"></span>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div> </div>
`);
     
        $("div.ok").append(content);
       }
        })

        })

</script>
```

But I'm getting the following result :

[image]

instead of :

[image]

I should remplace what I have in my html with the data extracted from database.

If you have any idea , please help

Comment: What is the result you currently get back?

Comment: you should console.log(casting) so you know what your fields are.  it looks like your casting. id_casting = 18,  what are your other fields?  like casting.slug  or casting.img_source  etc